# How to use Ansible to download all content from a particular folder in nexus/artifactory/webserver

Tags: ansible, synchronization, artifactory

first post on here.

I have a number of files with variable names (I don't choose them), but let's call them:

test1.rpm
pizza.rpm
pencil.tar

The names and extensions change (they are controlled by another team). What I would like to do, is have them available via a web resource e.g. Artifactory/Nexus in a known folder called INT1.

So I have a number of files in a folder called INT1 served by Artifactory/Nexus or something else.

I would like Ansible to effectively go to the known folder, and download all the items.

I have looked at the following:

- get_uri but generally you need a list of filenames (which I don't have)
- rsync - but this is more for filesystem to filesystem transfers

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like Ansible to effectively go to the known folder, and download all the items.

There is an "and" in your sentence, which corresponds to the two actions your playbook would need to take:

1. fetch the list of artifacts
2. fetch the artifacts based on that list

```yaml
- uri:
    url: '{{ artifactory_url }}/INT1'
    return_content: yes
  register: int1_response

- set_fact:
    the_urls: >-
      {# 
      here is where your code goes 
      to extract the list of files based 
      on the contents of whatever the server returns
      #}

- get_url:
    url: '{{ item }}'
    dest: /tmp/my/local/path/{{ item | basename }}
  with_items: '{{ the_urls }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an Ansible expert, but if the goal is to download the folder's content, with Artifactory you can either:

- Use the [RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) to download all items as an archive (tar, zip, etc)
- Use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) with patterns or AQL

Given a path, Artifactory makes it really easy to download the contents of a directory in a single step.